# Select Duplicates in ArcMap Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, file-geodatabase

I am trying to select duplicates from a feature class in a file geodatabase using the ArcMap Attribute Table. The query I am using is:

```
Address_ID In (SELECT Address_ID FROM "FoodRoutes_20180615" GROUP BY Address_ID HAVING Count(*)>1 )
```

It is returning an invalid SQL statement error. Do the table or field names need to be in brackets? Anything I may be missing? I also tried the table name without " " and received the same error.

Comment: You don't state what your data source is so no one can answer your question. Also have a look at [Find Identical](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) tool.

Comment: File geodatabase doesn't have an RDBMS behind it. 10.2 is probably too ancient to have some of the SQL implementation updates that occurred at 10.3 and 10.4 (and 10.5,  ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think a two step quick and dirty way of doing this is as follows:

1. (OPTIONAL IF THE OVERLAPPING FEATURES ARE PERFECTLY OVERLAPS)
   Self-union your data (pick your data as the only input)
2. Run Spatial
   Join tool by selecting ARE_IDENTICAL_TO match operator